# AngularJS ng-class multiple conditions with OR operator

Tags: angularjs, conditional-statements, ng-class

I try to find out the good syntax for adding classes depending on angular values.
I want to activate a class regarding 2 conditions (one on live user changes, and one on loading datas) with a OR operator.

Here is the line :

```
 <a href="" ng-click="addFavorite(myfav.id);favorite=!favorite">
    <i class="fa orange" ng-class="{'fa-star': (favorite || (fav==myfav.id)), 'fa-star-o': !favorite}"></i>
 </a>
```

I tried some different codes like this one :

```
 ng-class="{'fa-star': favorite, 'fa-star': (fav==myfav.id), 'fa-star-o': !favorite}"
```

without any success.
Can someone help me finding the good syntax ?

Comment: It should be `{'fa-star': favorite || fav == myfav.id, 'fa-star-o': !favorite}`. See a similar example in this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xDIzC0A50cXxMpIHeP3C?p=preview). I tried to replace that code with `ng-class="{'has-error': ctrl.submitted && 1 == 1}` and it works.

Comment: Parens should be working just as well. If I change your Plunkr code and add them to your AND expression, everything still works. I suppose OP has some other problem with their code.

Comment: Yes this was my first code but it seems it does not apply the class. I tested the `fav == myfav.id` outside and it returns "true" as it should be.

Comment: Oh. Could it be something about logic : if `!favorite` but `fav==myfav.id` the result would be both `fa-star` `fa-star-o` and then the last one applies and visually doesn't change the icon. So I'm not sure my "switch" works in this case

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this.

```
<a href="" ng-click="addFavorite(myfav.id);favorite=!favorite">
 <i class="fa orange" ng-class="{'fa-star': favorite || fav==myfav.id, 'fa-star-o': !favorite}"></i>
```

No need the brackets.

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. The alternate condition seems to be ignored when one model is updated.

Comment: @isherwood Did you mean, when variable favorite = false and fav == myFav.id? It will result in add both classes 'fa-star' and 'fa-star-o'.

Comment: The issue is with the OR operator, not the second class. When one of the conditions changes, it overrides the other condition.

Comment: @isherwood by override , what exactly do you mean, could you elaborate a bit. also if you could tell what exactly do you want should happen and its not happening , this would clear any wrong assumptions that we have made

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having trouble reproducing the issue I was seeing. I may have to retract.

Answer (score 10):

Once you have to add some logic behind `ng-class` it's always better to stick to using the controller to do that. You can do it two of either ways: JSON syntax (same as in your HTML, just more readable) or obviously JavaScript.

### HTML (JSON) Syntax

**HTML**

```
<i ng-class="getFavClassIcon(myFav.id)"></i>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getFavClassIcon= function (favId) {
    return {
        'fa-star-o' : !$scope.favorite,
        'fa-star'   : $scope.favorite || $scope.fav === favId
    };
};
```

### Good Old **IF-statement** (JavaScript)

**HTML**

```
<i ng-class="getFavClassIcon(myFav.id)"></i>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.getFavClassIcon= function (favId) {
    if (!$scope.favorite) {
        return 'fa-star-o';
    } else if ($scope.favorite) { // obviously you can use OR operator here
        return 'fa-star';
    } else if ($scope.fav === favId) {
        return 'fa-star';
    }
};
```

Comment: Old fashioned if is the best here, especially if multiple variables affect the class name

Comment: This is a brilliant way to do it - simple enough that anybody can pick it up and understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The HTML will remain the same

```
<a href="" ng-click="addFavorite(myfav.id);favorite=!favorite">
    <i ng-class="{'fa-star-o':!favorite,'fa-star':favorite||fav===myfav.id}"></i>
</a>
```

But the order in which classes are present in your CSS file will matter

The `fa-star` class will apply either when `favorite` is true or `fav===myfav.id` returns true.

Therefore if after clicking once , suppose `fav===myfav.id` returns true and keeps on returning true , even when clicking again , then the class `fa-star` will be applied always from then on.

If by default `favorite` is false , then `fa-star-o` will be applied when template is loaded the first time, but after the first click ,when `favorite` is set to true , it will get removed. Then on second click , when `favorite` is set to false again , `fa-star-o` it will get applied but in this case , `fa-star` class will also be applied as `fa===myfav.id` condition would be still returning true (Assuming that is the case).

Therefore you will need to prioritize which class needs to get applied for sure when it is present on the element as case can arise when both classes can be present at the same time on the element. For example if `fa-star-o` class takes higher priority, then put it below the `fa-star` in your CSS , like for example

```
.fa-star {
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
.fa-star-o {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

See working demo at http://plnkr.co/edit/Dh59KUU41uWpIkHIaYrO?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

You can use expression with ng-class

```
  <i class="fa orange" ng-class="favorite || fav == myfav.id ? 'fav' : 'no-fav'"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:
In my scenario i need to apply uppercase class in some condition and in some condition i do not need to apply that uppercase class.

```
inputTextCapitalSmall(assetId) {
    return {
      'uppercase': assetId !== 'TELEKURS' && assetId !== 'REUTERS' && assetId !== 'S&P',
    };
  }

<form [formGroup]="querySearchForm" >
  <input autocomplete="off" matInput id="assetIdTypeValue" [ngClass]="inputTextCapitalSmall(querySearchForm.value.assetIdType)" >
</form>
```