# How to add multiple conditions in ng-class using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I need to add multiple conditions `ng-class` using Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
<li ng-class="{'active':($root.stateName==='app.settings')}"><a ui-sref="app.settings">Settings</a></li>
```

Here I need to add another two conditions `i.e-$root.stateName==='app.settings.area' and $root.stateName==='app.settings.area.manageState'` with that existing conditions with `OR` condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS ng-class multiple conditions with OR operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287725/angularjs-ng-class-multiple-conditions-with-or-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Use an OR operator `||` in the evaluated expression:

```
<li ng-class="{'active':($root.stateName==='app.settings' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.area.manageState' )}">
    <a ui-sref="app.settings">Settings</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I did like this ` <li ng-class="{'active':($root.stateName==='app.settings' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.area' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.area.manageState' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.area.manageCity' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.vechile' || || $root.stateName==='app.settings.vechile.category' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.vechile.manufacture' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.vechile.model')}"><a ui-sref="app.settings.area.manageState">Settings</a></li>` but getting error.

Comment: @subhra Since you have so many conditions to meet, it is better to keep the logic at your controller and assign a variable so that your html can evaluate that variable

Answer (score 0):

I think this will also work

```
<li ng-class="{'active':($root.stateName==='app.settings' , $root.stateName==='app.settings.area.manageState'  } ">
             <a ui-sref="app.settings">Settings</a>  
              </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
`<li ng-class="{'active':($root.stateName==='app.settings' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.area' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.area.manageState' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.area.manageCity' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.vechile' || || $root.stateName==='app.settings.vechile.category' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.vechile.manufacture' || $root.stateName==='app.settings.vechile.model')}">
    <a ui-sref="app.settings.area.manageState">Settings</a>
</li>`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the blog which helps understanding all possible ways to use conditional ng-class

https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass